# How to handle long API request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an API which runs a query on database. Since the query execution time can be long, like 3 min to 10 min, my load balancer is returning *"upstream request timeout"*, but I can see the query is submitted to the datasource, but for the end user it's showing the wrong message. How to take care of this scenario?

My function

```
@PostMapping("/run/{QueryId}")
public void runQuery(@PathVariable String QueryId) {
     // This method takes long time
     querySchedulerService.runQuery(QueryId);
}
```

Comment: Does the end user expect for response? does it can be async? Does query or partial can be cached? Does the data source configured optimally? What kind of query ? huge tables? Multiple joins? In case end user should not receive response you should return HTTP_ACCEPTED and then to continue with the flow. BTW end user can be notifies after the query done.

Comment: Does this query should take so much time? try to think about data structure optimization like aggregation tables / partitioning / sharding beside your solution. try to reduce the processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
class SomeController{
 @PostMapping("/run/{QueryId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> runQuery(@PathVariable String QueryId) {
         // This method takes long time
         querySchedulerService.runQuery(QueryId);
         return new ResponseEntity<>(HTTP_STATUS.ACCEPTED);
    } 
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
class QuerySchedulerService{

    @Async
    public void runQuery(Query query){
    // Do somthing
    }
}
```

By adding `@EnableAsync` annotation in main `Application` class you can use `@Async` annotation

On every time that `runQuery` will called it will run in new thread.

```
@EnableAsync
class Application{

}
```

Comment: If i want to return the result ? how to handle this ?

Comment: Pulling or Pushing.. You can implement it with web sockets and then pushing the response to client. you can call to server again after X minutes with retries to pull the query response, you should store the query response as blob in new table [query id, query response ] or use unstructured data source such as MongoDB. you can create link and notify user by email.. I am not familiar with your business logic.

Comment: @Marcin_S my assumption based on your method return type. what kind of data you want to retrieve? Reports?